# asserting an error message matches a string in Django

Tags: django, django-unittest

Is this possible? I have an custom error message and I would like to check that it is raised when a validation is not met. Can I do something similar to the following?

`self.assertEqual(ValidationError.message, 'name validation not met')`

Comment: where you want to do that? in a test case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's like this:

```
with self.assertRaisesMessage(ValidationError, 'name validation not met'):
    # code that causes the exception
```

To have the `assertRaisesMessage` helper available, you should be working within a [Django `TestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase).